# How to check if record is updated?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to get updated records count from previous week. But I'm having trouble approaching the problem.

For Eg: I have a table 'Org'

week1 :

```
              id     name          age       address   date
  record1 :  123     Joe           35        xyz       12/01/2017
```

week2 :

```
              id     name          age       address     date
  record1 :  123     Joe           35        abc        12/03/2017
```

I'm trying to get the record which has been updated. In the above example, the address for record1 with id 123 has been updated. Currently I'm checking in an in-efficient way.

Query:

```
select * from Org where date='12/01/2017'
```

and

```
select * from Org where date='12/03/2017'
```

Query:

```
select distinct on (id) count(*) from Org group by Org.id
```

A file is being pushed to the db every day. So, the updated record will have a new timestamp and the records are getting aggregated overtime which made my job a little harder. I tried joining the table to itself but it didn't make any sense to me. I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I was trying and almost reaching the solution but I don't understand why I'm getting count two times. [Example Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3f906/1)

Comment: do you want the original record, or the updated record? given that a record has been updated. for later dumps, does the database only store records if there has been an update, or does it keep a record even if is unchanged since the previous version? Without knowing these features about your system, it would not be possible for us to help you solve the issue.

Comment: I want the count of updated ones. The data base stores every record even if there is no update. I edited the question with query I'm trying so far but still I'm not getting the right number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Query:

```
select col1 
from(
  select distinct col1,col2,col3,col4
  from table_not
    )D
group by col1
having count(1)>1
```

SQL Fiddle link: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/321ccf/2)